# How to uninstall DaisyDisk?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, software-recommendation

I followed some advice I found here for a replacement for Disk Inventory X

[OSX disk space shows 200GB as "other"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388549/osx-disk-space-shows-200gb-as-other#answer-388581)

I installed the DaisyDisk app and it worked very well, however now my machine is constantly overheating and mds_stores is consuming 99% of the cpu.

DaisyDisk does not appear in the Applications folder.

How do I uninstall it? Does anyone know?  They don't have any information on their website. I should have been more careful.

https://daisydiskapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to reinstall it and use "[AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)" to properly remove it and all of its remnants.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it from the App Store you can delete it from LaunchPad or Finder. Finder moving it to trash works for the direct download version of the app. Spotlight should reveal the location of the app in most cases.

Comment: I wasn't thinking when I installed it.  I downloaded it directly from them and unzipped and ran it.  It turns out it installed to ~/Applications and not /Applications so after deleteing it from ~/Applications and rebooting.  I think it's gone.  I hope.  :) Thank you